# There is no System Updates when I go to About Phone, please help?

Tags: applications, 4.4-kitkat, 5.0-lollipop, 6.0-marshmallow, updates

recently I bought YotaPhone 2 from Aliexpress, and I wanted to update its android which is currently version 4.4.3, and when I go to Settings and About Phone, the first thing from the top is Status, and there is no System Updates option, my phone's processor is Qualcomm MSM8974PRO-AA. please help me.

Answer (score 0):

The system updates differ from country to country or varies place to place. Same phone from one place may be provided with an update whereas same phone from another place cannot be updated. The reason for you not getting might just be this.

But please recheck :

According to [GSM ARENA](http://www.gsmarena.com/yota_yotaphone_2-6959.php) you phone can be updated to 5.0.

Also update is the must the flashing a custom rom is also an option.

Comment: Thank you so much for your info, yeah I think it might be reason of that, but if so, what is an alternative way to update my Yotaphone? I'm from Kurdistan of Iraq, and as I know the update is not available for my country, and the update is available for my phone in other countries. 

What is flashing? can I update my phone with that? thanks